# Calling a Sling Servlet From java code

Tags: http, url, jakarta-ee, post, sling

I am trying to call a servlet via HTTP POST from my java code.Below is my code

```
private void sendRequest(String Url)
{
  //Url contains all the POST parameters

try {

        URL url = new URL(Url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true); 
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.connect();
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

But the request is not going to the servlet. I tried to reach the URL via browser and it's working fine.Am I missing something or is there any problem with the code.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is to process a request through a running sling, you might want to check the [Sling Request Processor](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/engine/SlingRequestProcessor.html)  . you can process request to the Sling engine with that service.

Additionaly, if you are using CQ, you can use the [Request Response Factory](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/contentsync/handler/util/RequestResponseFactory.html) to create the request that you pass to the request processor

Answer (score 0):

You're nowhere actually **sending** the HTTP request. Only connecting/disconnecting is not sufficient. In case of `URLConnection` the HTTP request will only be sent when your code starts to obtain information about the HTTP response, such as response status, headers and/or body.

Replace those unnecessary `connect()` and `disconnect()` lines by e.g.

```
int responseStatusCode = connection.getResponseCode(); // 200 == OK.
```

or

```
InputStream responseBody = connection.getInputStream();
// Consume it.
```

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)